# Why my d3 line chart only has two ticks on x axis?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, linechart

My data is something like this:

```
[
  {"months": ["2012.10","2012.11"], "score": 0.1048387096775},
  {"months": ["2012.11","2013.1" ], "score": 0.1048387096775},
  {"months":["2013.1","2013.2"],"score":0.45362903225749995},
  {"months":["2013.2","2013.3"],"score":0.4912023460409091},
  ...
]
```

The x axis shows the months in the form of `2012.10 & 2012.11`; the y axis shows the score accordingly. However, the x axis only has two ticks and the line chart turns into a weird shape.

Here is my code: http://plnkr.co/edit/uX8ctTEJy5lDs7LWY0Pq?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using an [ordinal scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales). Ordinal scales are a map between the domain values to range values. I think that you may want to use an actual date (the end of the first month, for instance) and set the label to have both values. Take a look at the [`avg.axis.tickFormat`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-tickFormat) documentation.

Comment: I would like the chart to be a continuous line like a timeline, and x axis shows all the "months" as ticks in the array. Even if I change to "range", the x axis still only shows two ticks.

Comment: Actually, the problem is that you are using ordinal scales wrong, you probably want to use a linear scale. I updated the answer.